# performSegueWithIdentifier causes crash

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6, segue

I'm setting up a sign up/login page using framework PARSE on XCode 6.

When I try to perform a segue (it is spelled correcty), hover, the app crash, even though the segue is inside an if statement.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

   var signUpMode = false

   func displayAlert(title:String, message:String){        
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
   }

   //Outlet and actions    

   @IBOutlet var username: customTextField!    
   @IBOutlet var email: customTextField!  
   @IBOutlet var password: customTextField!

   //Need the outlets for changes betweeen signUp and logIn modes!!!


   @IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

      if signUpMode == true {

         var user = PFUser()
         user.username = username.text
         user.password = password.text
         user.email = email.text

         // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
         //user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

         user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            } else {
                println("error")
                self.displayAlert("Username already in use", message: "Please use another username")
            }
         }
      }
      else {

         PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(email.text, password:password.text) {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if user != nil {                    
                self.displayAlert("You're in", message: "And you'll be successful")                    
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToPost", sender: self)                    
            } else {                    
                self.displayAlert("Wrong username or password", message: "Please try again")
            }
        }
   }    


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

      if signUpMode == false {            
          self.username.hidden = true
          self.email.placeholder = "username"           
      }        
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

      if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {            
          performSegueWithIdentifier("goToPost", sender: self)            
      }      
  }
}
```

The segue is inside the `viewWillAppear` method.
`PFUser().currentUser()` stores information about the current logged in user, so it's `nil` if no user is logged in.

Can you find out why it crashes?
I tried to put the segue inside `viewDidLoad`, but nothing else, it didn't even crashed.

Comment: Please post the error please.

Comment: I only get a SIGABRT on the AppDelegate.swift @Schemetrical

Comment: Yeah but what does the SIGABRT say? Did you mislink something on the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try segueing in viewDidAppear: and check if your segue identifier matches the one on your storyboard.